# Using counts and tfidf as features with scikit learn

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, nlp

I'm trying to use both counts and `tfidf` as features for a multinomial Naive Bayes model. Here's my code:

```
text = ["this is spam", "this isn't spam"]
labels = [0,1]
count_vectorizer = CountVectorizer(stop_words="english", min_df=3)

tf_transformer = TfidfTransformer(use_idf=True)
combined_features = FeatureUnion([("counts", self.count_vectorizer), ("tfidf", tf_transformer)]).fit(self.text)

classifier = MultinomialNB()
classifier.fit(combined_features, labels)
```

But I'm getting an error with `FeatureUnion` and `tfidf`:

```
TypeError: no supported conversion for types: (dtype('S18413'),)
```

Any idea why this could be happening? Is it not possible to have both counts and tfidf as features?

Answer (score 12):

The error didn't come from the `FeatureUnion`, it came from the `TfidfTransformer`

You should use `TfidfVectorizer` instead of `TfidfTransformer`, the transformer expects a numpy array as input and not plaintext, hence the TypeError

Also your test sentence is too small for Tfidf testing so try using a bigger one, here's an example:

```
from nltk.corpus import brown

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer, TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.pipeline import FeatureUnion
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB

# Let's get more text from NLTK
text = [" ".join(i) for i in brown.sents()[:100]]
# I'm just gonna assign random tags.
labels = ['yes']*50 + ['no']*50
count_vectorizer = CountVectorizer(stop_words="english", min_df=3)
tf_transformer = TfidfVectorizer(use_idf=True)
combined_features = FeatureUnion([("counts", count_vectorizer), ("tfidf", tf_transformer)]).fit_transform(text)
classifier = MultinomialNB()
classifier.fit(combined_features, labels)
```